# question on subgroups of prime order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and let $\,H,\, K\,$ be subgroups of $\,G,\,$ each of order $\,p,\,$ where $\,p\,$ is prime.
>   Show that either $\,H\cap K =\{e\},\,$ or $\,H=K.\,$
>
> Is the result true if $\,p\,$ is not a prime number?   Justify your answer.

Comment: You could try using a better title.

Comment: The title you used belongs in the tags. A real title gives hints to the contents of the question, so that other people with the same question can find it.

Comment: Please give us some context for this problem.  Why are you interested in it?  What do you want us to help with?  What have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If we know what you've tried, we can have a better idea what you have to work with, and better answer your question.

Comment: Kamal, some of us get annoyed when people copy-paste questions from unidentified sources without giving any indication of why they want to answer the question, or whether they have done any work, or what they know about the question. Questions like this run the risk of rapidly getting closed.

Comment: The stated reason for closure is rubbish, as is clearly demonstrated by the existence of two perfectly good answers. The only debates likely to be solicited by the question concern the (im)propriety of closing it.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming that you want $H,K$ subgroups of $G$, rather than $H<K$ subgroups (probably just a capitalization typo!)

Hint: $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$ and of $K$. What are the possible orders of subgroups of a prime order group?

After you answer that hint, you should be much more clear on the possiblities for what $H\cap K$ is.

As for the second half of the question, look at something simple like $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$. Try looking at some obvious order 4 subgroups.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $H$ and $K$ are both cyclic, so let $H$ be generated by $a$.  What if $K$ contains  $a$?  What if it doesn't?